# Uninstall MS Office 2010 after installation partition is gone

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, uninstall

On one of my PCs Microsoft Office 2010 was installed on partition D. After some reconfiguration this partition (which was on another harddrive) is gone and cannot be restored.

Now I am unable to uninstall Microsoft Office. The installation wizard fails and gives me error 1324. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to install it again? Perhaps, repair installation and than uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-uninstall-or-remove-Microsoft-Office-2010-suites-90635a1d-aec8-4653-b358-67e1b766fc4d?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) for detailed steps on manually uninstalling Office 2010. I have not posted the details here as it is very long. See if helps. Else the only solution is formatting the machine and installing a fresh copy of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

> Revo Uninstaller Pro has a very powerful feature called **Forced Uninstall** Forced Uninstall is the best solution when you have to remove stubborn programs, partially installed programs, partially uninstalled programs, and programs not listed as installed at all!

Also you can take a look at this free software: http://www.puransoftware.com/Uninstaller.html